# Do generic types on complex linked structure like tree or graph run slow?

Tags: java, generics

Curently in my Java project i need to use complex linked data structures  like linked lists, trees, grahps, fibornatti heaps. To make the code more reusable , i am using a generic types for each node in the structure, for example **class GraphNode  < T > .** The nodes are generally accessed via its references.
Is it generally known, will this code be slower compare to the **same** operations without generics (like   **class GraphNode **) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is little performance loss with generics, except for casts occurring sometimes. The JVM erases generic information and treats your generics as `GraphNode<Object>` AKA the raw type `GraphNode`.

Answer (score 0):

Since generics is a compile time mechanism (implemented with type erasure), the actual code has no difference whether or not you're using generics. So the answer is "no, it won't be slower".